# Is it possible to conditionally update a nullable long without locking?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, interlocked

I have `long? startTime` to hold start time.

I have multiple threads with non-`async` methods updating `startTime` and there's another `async` method in a separate thread that only ever read this value. The methods that update the value do so as below:

```
if (startTime == null || (newValue != 0 && newValue < startTime))
{
    startTime = newValue;
}
```

The issue is that, writer threads are updating `startTime` at a very very high frequency causing a lot of contention for the lock. So, is there any way I can do this without locking (or a better locking mechanism over a normal lock)?

I'm thinking of using `Interlocked` but because of the `if` clause, I think this is not correct?

EDIT: I can change it to a non-nullable if needed.

Comment: You cannot use `Interlocked` because it doesn't support `Nullable<long>`.

Comment: Instead of long may you use int64.

Comment: @GabrielPereira, `Int64` is `long`.

Comment: Largest size supported for interlocked operations is 64 bits (at least exposed in .NET). A `Nullable<T>` is at least `sizeof(bool) + sizeof(T)`, so for `long` you're definitely going over.

Comment: I don't see any locking in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From end of question:

> EDIT: I can change it to a non-nullable if needed.

For the non-nullable `long`, you need a check and update loop (something like this):

```
var current = Interlocked.Read(ref startTime);
while(current > newValue)
{
  var other = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref startTime, newValue, current);
  if(other==current) break;
  current = other;
}
```

You can make your while clause conditions arbitrarily complex, they're effectively your `if` check. You may also want/need to recompute `newValue` inside the loop as well.

The `Interlocked.Read` obtains you the initial value. The `Interlocked.CompareExchange` does "if the value is still the same as when I last read the value, commit my change" and also obtains the new current value if the value had changed.

Other things to consider - do you actually need this "start time" value or could a simple incrementing integer stand in it's place? That would be `Interlocked.Increment` with no looping and no locking, so may be worth considering if write contention is still high here, if you can modify the other parts of your code appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! Why do we use a `while` instead of a `if`?

Comment: You don't have to, but it covers "The value of `current` I used in evaluating my condition isn't the value it has now". Quite often, if that new value would *also* have satisfied your condition, you want to still put your "even better" `newValue` in its place. So we loop until the condition isn't satisfied at all. (It's possible with different conditions that `newValue` *would* satisfy the condition and product an endless loop, which is why I always include the extra `break` bit too).